# Enforcing row immutability via trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a definition similar to the following (condensed for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE fns(
  id serial,
  start_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  end_date timestamptz,
  name text NOT NULL,
  parent_id integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES fns(id),
  UNIQUE(name)
);
```

When an `UPDATE` takes place I would like the row being 'updated' to have its `end_date` set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and to have a new row created (based on the old one) with its `start_date` set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. For example:

**Before `UPDATE`**

```
| id |              start_date | end_date |  name | parent_id |
|----|-------------------------|----------|-------|-----------|
|  1 | April, 01 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) | fns_a |    (null) |
```

**Desired state after `UPDATE`**

```
| id |              start_date |                end_date |        name | parent_id |
|----|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------|-----------|
|  1 | April, 01 2015 00:00:00 | April, 02 2015 00:00:00 | fns_a [old] |    (null) |
|  2 | April, 02 2015 00:00:00 |                  (null) |       fns_a |         1 |
```

I'm running into issues with the unique constraint for the `name` column. Here is the current state of my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enfore_fns_immutability() RETURNS trigger AS $func$
BEGIN
  -- 'Turn off' old record.
  OLD.end_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  OLD.name = OLD.name || ' [old]';

  -- Create the new record.
  INSERT INTO fns(start_date, name, parent_id)
    VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW.name, OLD.id); -- <-- unique violation

  RETURN OLD;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_fns_bi
  BEFORE UPDATE ON fns
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE enforce_fns_immutability();
```

As far as I understand it this is failing because the update to `OLD.name` has not yet happened as the containing transaction has not committed. I'm struggling to think of a way around it but it feels like there must be an elegant solution for this! Some solutions I've considered:

- Temporary table (feels like this is too heavyweight for this use case).
- Use of an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger (same issue as the transaction has obviously not yet been committed).

I'm using **Postgres 9.4.1**.

Comment: There is a deleted answer from @RadekPostołowicz which I think is valid as well: you could also create a partial unique index (as opposed to unique _constraint_) with the condition `where parent_id is null`. That way you can even keep the original name and don't need to append `[old]` to it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks :) I think the partial unique constraint wouldn't work for us due to the scenario where there were two edit mades. In that case we would have two records where `parent_id is null`.

Comment: Btw in the real code we're using a timestamp component in the modified name so we wouldn't end up with two being called `fns_a [old]` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the unique constraint as deferred, in that case it will be checked when you `commit` your transaction, not when the `insert` is executed:

```
CREATE TABLE fns
(
  id serial,
  start_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  end_date timestamptz,
  name text NOT NULL,
  parent_id integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES fns(id),
  UNIQUE(name) deferrable initially deferred --<< here
);
```

Comment: Out of interest, why is the `INITIALLY` required? Is it as the behaviour could be modified by `SET CONSTRAINTS` subsequently?

Comment: @jabclab: yes. I think the default is `initially immediate` which means you would need to change that each time you run an `update` statement (but even if I'm wrong and the default is `initially deferred` I prefer to state my intentions clearly ;)